# My raspberry pi only have the green led on (model B+)

Tags: hardware, power-supply

Yesterday I connected my RPi to the TV, but there was a problem. The red LED doesn't blink, but the green LED is on. I've change the microSD but It didn't help.

I use a 700 mA power supply, and tried powering it from my laptop USB port.

Comment: Does your Pi work?  If it does it may simply be that the green and red LEDs were swapped.  The power (red) LED should be the closest to the expansion header.

Comment: ok,i've ask on the raspberry pi forum,it was the PSU,i've change it to 1000mAh aand it work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The red light is PWR led and it is steady ON when Pi receives some power.
If the red power LED does not light it means that power is not properly connected or sufficient.

Typically, the model B uses between 700-1000mA depending on what peripherals are connected, the Model B+ has slightly more efficient power circuits as well as more available USB ports and can use between 600-2000mA.

So make sure your power supply delivers the specified values and it should work fine!